# Password validation while typing didn't work with special characters in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I'm a new developer and I'm actually trying to do a password who check while typing if there are the good characters.

For this, I did RegExp, for uppercase, numbers, and special characters.

Uppercase and numbers working well but I don't know why special characters won't work.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<p class="maj">uppercase</p>
<p class="number">number</p>
<p class="carspe">special chracters</p>
<p class="carac">min 8 characters</p>
```

CSS

```
.maj{
  color:red;
}

.number{
  color:red;
}

.carac{
  color:red;
}

.carspe {
  color:red;
}
```

JS

```
var input = document.querySelector('.input');
var maj = document.querySelector('.maj');
var number = document.querySelector('.number');
var carspe = document.querySelector('.carspe');
var carac = document.querySelector('.carac');

var uppercase = /[A-Z]/g;
var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
var carspe = /[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/g;

input.addEventListener('input', function() {

  if (input.value.match(uppercase)) {
    maj.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    maj.style.color = 'red';
  }

  if (input.value.match(numbers)) {
    number.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    number.style.color = 'red';
  }

  if (input.value.length >= 8) {
    carac.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    carac.style.color = 'red';
  }

  if (input.value.match(carspe)) {
    carspe.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    carspe.style.color = 'red';
  }


})
```

Thanks for take time to learn my problem and for the future help <3

Comment: You are defining `var carspe` 2 times. Try for example `var specialChars = /[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/g;` and `if (input.value.match(specialChars)) {`

Comment: Oh yes ! You right :) I did it and then it work better than before <3

Comment: Thanks you and have a nice day ! :p